# How to subscribe to BOOT_COMPLETED event?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I want to subscribe to the **BOOT_COMPLETED intent action**, which signals the restart of the mobile phone. Once I subscribe I want to schedule some alarms. I have a BroadcastReceiver that listens to the BOOT_COMPLETED action and it gets hit/called if I use android **SDK 25**. How can I make the code in BroadcastReceiver execute from Android **SDK 26 (Oreo)** and above ?

When I run the code on sdk 26 I get the error:
`system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x400010 }`

I have created a **Github repo** https://github.com/Ferencz8/BootIntent on a simpler case, which shows exactly how on sdk 25 things work and on 26 they don't.

Here is the **AndroidManifest.xml** part:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

And the **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(BootReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "In Boot Receiver");
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

I have tried in the OnReceive method from the BroadcastReceiver to start a ForegroundService like, but with no luck:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context,final  Intent intent) {
        intent.setClass(context, AlarmBootService.class);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(intent);
        }
        else{
            context.startService(intent);
        }
}
```

I have also tried adding other intent actions besides the BOOT_COMPLETED:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
```

In order **to simulate** the **BOOT_COMPLETED** action I used the command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Also, this is my first question so if you have any feedback on how to describe/articulate better my question please do tell :).

Comment: pretty sure you shouldnt start and activity onboot - it is meant for registering services

Comment: @jonathanHeindl, I agree with you. I started an activity in order to test if the code works.

Comment: try this one : 
`AlarmManager alarmManager =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);`

and then set an alarm on it

Comment: Thanks, but I already made the setting of alarm part. My issue is that I can't reschedule them after reboot, because the event does not get fired. In the github sample, I only added the firing of event part, without the alarm, because that is where I am stuck at.